# AngularJS: Define variables on view load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code for my controller:

```
app.controller("consoleCtrl", function($scope,$http,loginFactory){
$scope.emp = [];    

//Load logged in employee data:
loginFactory.bootConsole().success(function(data){
    console.log("Data retrieved from servlet: " + data);
    $scope.emp = data;
});

console.log("Data stored in variable: " + $scope.emp);
}
```

and this function for my factory:

```
bootConsole: function(){
        return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/EmployeeAngular/Console");
    }
```

The data gets retrieved just fine when I run the bootconsole function in the factory, but it doesn't load it into the variable $scope.emp. Is there a way to load a function on view render? I tried using ng-init but that didn't help.

The View:

```
<body ng-controller="consoleCtrl">
....
<div id="proPic">{{personal.img}}</div>
                    <div id="name">{{personal.fname}} {{personal.lname}}</div>
                    <div id="add1">{{personal.street}}</div>
                    <div id="add2">{{personal.city}}, {{personal.state}} {{personal.zip}}</div>
                    <div id="email">{{personal.email}}</div>
                    <div id="role">{{personal.role}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your view in this case? Also does the "Data retrieved.." log happen?

Comment: I could post the view but its very very long. According to the console, "data stored..." runs first then the "Data retrieved" runs. the data variable contains the correct data but its not passed to $scope.emp.

Comment: If the view is too big, it'll be helpful if you post the part of the view that uses `emp` or create a JsFiddle with simple view/controller/factory that reproduces this problem.

Comment: No where in the view you posted is a reference to `$scope.emp`

Comment: I tried wrapping the factory function in an init() function for the controller and putting that in an ng-init="init()" but that didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Your view has nor reference to any `emp` property from your `$scope`, but I assume what's blocking you is that you're asynchronously fetching data, so your View is not updated even if you put it in `$scope.emp`

An easy way to solve that is to apply your scope whithin the callback so the view is updated:

```
//Load logged in employee data:
loginFactory.bootConsole().success(function(data) {
  console.log("Data retrieved from servlet: " + data);
  // Run an angular digest cycle to properly update the view
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.emp = data;
    console.log("Data stored in variable: " + $scope.emp);
  });
});
```

Comment: Would you suggest using this function outside the controller?

Comment: No, never manipulate your `$scope` outside of a controller, that's against the design pattern and would bring more problems. It's okay to call `$scope.$apply` within your controller.